# Oil pan and timing cover gaskets replacement worth it?

Tags: oil-leak, mercury

I have a beautiful 2009 Mercury Mariner. Got her used at 147k miles and she's now at 154k and i'm really hoping to have her for awhile.  I've just run into a few problems.

1. I found out recently my mariner has an oil leak coming from the oil pan gasket and timing cover gasket. I've done my research and obviously its a pretty expensive repair. I was gonna just have my shop replace the oil pan gasket first, then save some money to come back and get the timing cover gasket replaced considering that is the more expensive repair of the two.   I guess my question also is, is my 09 mariner worth it?
2. I recently got my ball joints replaced which I do notice a difference in driving.  I actually went into the shop hoping to get the whole control arm replaced along with the ball joints but both mechanics I went to told me they couldn't get the control arm off, because it was sealed in pretty good so they just replaced the ball joints. Should I be worried the control arm won't come off?

Does anybody else have a mariner running beautifully?  Please comment, I would love to hear from other escape/mariner drivers.

Comment: Yes, it's worth it if everything else ia fine. Your car can last many years if properly maintained.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  It looks to me like this question is rather opinion-based.  The way this site works is that we need questions that have a definite answer, and it seems to me that it would be hard to come up with an objective answer to "is it worth it?".  Could you edit your question to fit within [the scope](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: A car is worth it if you expect to get more driving out of it than the cost of replacing it.  A used car always needs some kind of work, and while ~150k used to be a lot, its really only middle aged for a modern car.   Consider that your time cost can be subtracted from "garage costs" to come up with a smaller value for "cost" which may be more favourable than the  "worth-doing?" number.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider replacing the Valve cover gaskets first.

That was my experience.  They leak over the engine and make it look like the timing cover gaskets are leaking when they may actually be OK.  It's a much less expensive repair and may solve your problem.

Also I read in this forum that using Lucas Oil seal with every oil change will dramatically reduce the oil leakage from the timing cover gaskets at a much lower price.